# How to fix react native apk not updating issue

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-cli

Now I have been learning to react-native on mac os. After I create a react native project, and I built it. It works fine. After I modified some parts of this project, my app-debug apk file was created according to rebuilding. On the emulator, it works as well, but on the other android device, such as Bluestack, android phone, it does not update.
So I tried some steps for fixing.
If any someone has experiences in this, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

can use

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

or

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

then

```
cd android

gradlew clean
```